# What is the _setActiveMenu function in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't understand the _setActiveMenu function in Magento 1..
Usually it is used with the loadLayout function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_setActiveMenu` is used to make menu tab module selected when that layout is loaded

example :

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()
         ->_setActiveMenu('module_name') // the module menu will be selected
         ->_title($this->__('Title page here')); // title page
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do _setActiveMenu(), Magento highlights the specified menu just for user to know which menu is active. Something like this (here you see "Reports" is an active menu).

[image]

Parameter passed throught _setActiveMenu should be the one specified in config.xml `<adminhtml> <menu>` tag.

Hope it finds helpful.